# how to set keycode value while triggering keypress event manually in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, keypress, keyboard-events

I am new to Javascript, though i have used JQuery well. But i cant find a better documentation for doing this . The click event need to be triggered only if i press enter key. so i need to write test case for this scenario.

```
function btnRepeatKeyDownEvent(e){
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            this.trigger('click', e);
        }
}
```

so far i have found this solution.

```
let keyboardEvent: KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key': 'Enter'});
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```

but the above code always give keycode value as 0. i am more tired for finding the solution. As per MDN most of the functionalities are deprecated. 
i need to made this test case workable in chrome, firefox and IE11+ only not for old browsers.Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyCode and other properties are Read Only.  So, you can fake it, taking advantage of JavaScript's   **Object.defineProperties** function that does overwrite values:

```
function makeKeyPressEvent(keyName, keyCode, charCode){
    var event = new KeyboardEvent('keypress');
    Object.defineProperties(event, {
        charCode: {value: charCode},
        keyCode: {value: keyCode},
        keyIdentifier: {value: keyName},
        which: {value: keyCode}
    });
    return event;
}
```

here is how to use it:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){console.log('key pressed!', event.keyIdentifier, event.keyCode, event.charCode, event)}, true);

var enterKeyEvent = makeKeyPressEvent('Enter', 13, 13);

window.dispatchEvent(enterKeyEvent);
```

Comment: TypeError: Attempting to change access mechanism for an unconfigurable property in phantomJs -- :(