# How to move caret «home» or «end» use fn+arrow key JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, keyboard-events

How to repeat behaviour CMD+arrowLeft (Home) and CMD+arrowRight (End) for fn+arrowLeft and fn+arrowRight as well.
Please write code if existed another approach to move caret (cursor) to the begin or to the end of input field use combination of keys. I use MacOs.

- 36 - event.key for fn+arrowLeft
- 35 - event.key for fn+arrowRight

```
const handleKey = (e) => {
    if (e.metaKey || e.altKey || e.ctrlKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (e.key === 'Home') {
      // code here
    }
    if (e.key === 'End') {
      // code here
    }
  };
```

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="handleKey()">
```

As alternative way but doesn’t cover my need:
[Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-keyboard-caret-position-in-html-textbox/512542#512542)

I assumed that good way but don’t know how use right KeyboardEvent object:
[how to set keycode value while triggering keypress event manually in pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605601/how-to-set-keycode-value-while-triggering-keypress-event-manually-in-pure-javasc)

Comment: Could you explain the *"doesn’t cover my need"* part?

Comment: @TJ I mean theirs approaches are close to resolve my problem but I can’t apply it to my code, for example: **KeyboardEvent** object read-only however **CMD+arrowLeft**  should replace by **fn+arrowLeft** - that is problem.

Comment: I don't think the OS (or the browser) can "see" the fn key. The keyboared does translation and then sends those results to the OS (and browser). So, if fn+left gets you a home key press, you'd want to detect a home key press (without meta, alt, or ctrl). https://keycode.info/ can tell you what the browser is seeing.